# Objective-C staying in a JSONRequest loop until JSON returns a specific value

Tags: objective-c, json, request

I am implementing an HTTP request using Objective-C using AFJSONRequestOperation for a mobile app and I do not know how to implement a loop until a condition is satisfied (i.e. the profiling_status key in JSON has the value 1). The request is run when a button is pressed. In the background the server does some calculations that take a while. Until the server finishes, the profiling_status value is 2. When it finishes the value is 1. So, I would like to stay in a loop until the value changes to 1 and then display the JSON.

Returning the JSON in the success block gives a pointer error.. and returning the JSON at the end of the method will return nil.

I have this code:

```
 - (IBAction)getProfileInfo:(id)sender
 {

    profiling_status = 2;
    NSDictionary *JSON;

    while (profiling_status == 2){
        JSON = [self getJSON];
        profiling_status = [JSON objectForKey:@"profiling_status"];
    }

    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", JSON);

  }

  - (NSDictionary*)getJSON
  {
      __block NSDictionary* JSONResult = nil;


      MyAPIClient *client = [MyAPIClient sharedClient];

      NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/profile?json"];
      NSURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:path parameters:nil];

      AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

            JSONResult = JSON;
            //can’t do this ---- return JSONResult;   

      } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id   JSON) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error userInfo]);
      }];

      [operation start];

      return JSONResult; //will return nil

    }
```

Any help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a while loop for this (and shouldn't anyway as it will just kill the app by spawning connections). Instead you need to structure your methods with blocks so that the block running the request checks the result and either recursively calls the check method (preferably after a short delay) or calls a completion block.

Also think about keeping a count of the number of iterations or the time taken so you can abort the processing.